# Unable to send json generated OTP as an sms to phoneNumber in Swift

Tags: json, swift3, sms, phone-number, one-time-password

I am adding phone number in phoneNumTextField after that when i tap on registerButton i need to send otp as a sms to that phone number. but here i am unable to send otp to phone sms. i am getting otp in json i stored that otp in otpField i need to send that otp to that phone number. i have imported import MessageUI and i added MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate to viewcontroller.

here is my code:

```
func registerService(){

print("register tapped")

let parameters = ["mobile_number": Int(phoneNumTextField.text ?? ""),] as? [String : Any]

let url = URL(string: "https://dev.anyemi.com/webservices/anyemi/register")
var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
req.httpMethod = "POST"
req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
req.httpBody = httpBody

let session = URLSession.shared

session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        // print(response)
    }
    if let data = data {

        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
            print("the json regggggggggggis \(json)")

            self.otpField = json["otp"] as? Int

            if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText())
            {
                let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
                controller.body = self.otpField as? String
                controller.recipients = [self.phoneNumTextField.text] as! [String]

                controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error!!!!!")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.otpTextField.text = self.otpField as? String
            }

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }
}).resume()
}


 @IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {
        registerService()
 }
```

when i tap on registerButton
MFMessageComposeViewController is going to else part i am getting EError!!!!!.

Is this correct or do i need to add any framework for otp send as sms to message box.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please help me in above issue or suggest me if there is any framework. i am new to ios i will learn.

Comment: you are debugging app on simulator?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so its an issue with code,

you cannot use messageController on simulator devices use real device instead or you are testing app on a device that don't support messages.

Comment: yes i am testing app in simulator. i need one clarification and that is ,can we send OTP as a sms to phone by using MFMessageComposeViewController or do i need to add any framework to send otp sms to phone, this is the first time i am dealing with otp, before i use just email and password for registration. please clarify my doubt.

Comment: In ideal case your otp should be sent by server, if sending OTP via MFMessageController is your requirement you may go with this, if it will be a bad practice apple will let you know in application review.

Comment: yes i am getting OTP from json and i can read OTP from xcode console and i am able to register but i need to send that OTP to phone messages that is my requirement.

Comment: i  told you instead of getting in json send number to server and ask server to send it to phone number

Comment: aslo please accept the answer if it resolves your problem or you if you got reason for error :) .

Comment: sure i will accept ur answer, before suggest me how can we send json generated otp for regisered phone number to that phone messages

Comment: There are several api's on server side that can send messages to phone append your https://dev.anyemi.com/webservices/anyemi/register api functionality with sending  OTP functionality too if phone number is valid.